# Error message when writing to the Windows Event Log

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, event-log, sharepoint-workflow

When I run a piece of code that I wrote I keep getting the following error:

> The source was not found, but some or
>   all event logs could not be searched. 
>   Inaccessible logs: Security.

I have double checked and I am not manually writing to the logs anywhere, so I assume my application is doing it on it's own.

I found [this post](http://www.digcode.com/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=437), which suggest that I give read/write permissions to a registry entry that corresponds to the Event Logs.  I had three questions about this:

1. Is this the correct way to fix this
   error?
2. If I go this route, should I give permissions to whatever my app pool is running under? (it's a web app)
3. Is it secure to give read/write access to that registry key?

Comment: can you send the full stacktrace?

Comment: I could be missing something, but it seems like you would be better served trying to figure out why code that isn't supposed to write to the event log *is* writing to the event log and what source it's using, if you figure out why that is. The source may simply need to be set up so it can write to it.

Comment: I did a quick string search with reflector in most of the .Net 4 assemblies and it didn't find the exact error message there. What framework are you on? Any specific assemblies?

Comment: @rene, I am using 3.5 and this is a SharePoint workflow.

Comment: @Andrew, It seems to me that it SHOULD be writing to the event logs, but it simply does not have the required permissions.  Why do you say that the code "isn't supposed to write to the event log"?  If my application has something to log, I would like to see it.

Comment: @Davide, I'll see if I can dig it up.  Since I am going through SharePoint seeming small things like getting a stack trace are surprisingly difficult...

Comment: Ok, the message is coming from System.Diagnostics.CreateEventSource and it popsup when it can't acces one of the registry entries under SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog. If you could figure out what the eventsoure name is that is being created, add that source to an eventlog, you'll also get rid of this particular message...

Comment: This may help: http://goo.gl/IirtH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely seems like a permissions issue.  It has to do with the fact that the Source you are trying to write into the event log does not already exist.  Once it is created, this error should go away.  Since you just need to make sure the Source gets added that first time, you could try the registry approach (grant access to the AppPool user), and then remove the registry access after the source has been created.

I've worked around this issue by manually adding the Source to the Event Log using a dialog app I wrote that I run as Administrator.  Once the Source is added, all of the other event logging works fine.  If you know the Source that it's trying to use when it writes to the event log, you could try that approach as well.

Comment: Is it possible that it only THINKS it doesn't exist because it can't even read the registry key?

Comment: Possibly, but I haven't seen that happen before. I've come across this error quite a bit and for my applications it always goes away after the source is created. I would probably start debugging this by changing security settings in the registry so I could get one entry added, and then I would revert those changes to see if the logging still worked.  If you are in iis then you'll probably need an iisreset or at least an app pool recycle between changes.